# Probability that median falls within a range?

Tags: probability

If I draw 5 samples from a distribution that is cont., what is the probability that the median of the population is between the xmin and xmax of the draw samples?

What is the formula to apply here?

Comment: The sample median or the median of the distribution? What is known about the distribution (e.g. is it normal with unknown or known parameters? or is it another distribution with known or unknown parameters?)

Comment: @Sycorax I updated the original post the original information I have on hand. I hope this helps.

Comment: If $\tilde{\mu}$ is the population median, can you work out the probability of observing all sample values $<\tilde{\mu}$? Can you work out the probability of observing all sample values $>\tilde{\mu}$?

Comment: @Glen_b I am not sure what you are asking. Could you please clarify?

Comment: I was trying to guide you toward a very easy way to see the answer for yourself by computing the probability of the complementary event (which has two mutually exclusive subevents). The probabilities of these events are very simple to calculate

Comment: Don't delete a post and repost it. If there was some problem with your question, edit the original. You waste the effort people spend on your original. In particular the claim "I have no starting point" is untrue, given the hints already given.

Comment: Two versions of the same question have been merged.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $m$ denote the true median of the distribution.  Since the distribution is continuous, by definition there is a probability of one-half that a given value will fall above/below the median.  Hence, you have:

$$\mathbb{P}(X_{(1)} > m) = \prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb{P}(X_i > m) = \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2^n},$$

$$\mathbb{P}(X_{(n)} < m) = \prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb{P}(X_i < m) = \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2^n}.$$

Putting this together and using the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) you get:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\mathbb{P}(X_{(1)} \leqslant m \leqslant X_{(n)})
&= 1 - \mathbb{P}(X_{(1)} > m \ \text{ or } \ X_{(n)} < m) \\[6pt]
&= 1 - \mathbb{P}(X_{(1)} > m) - \mathbb{P}(X_{(n)} < m) + \mathbb{P}(X_{(n)} < m < X_{(1)}) \\[6pt]
&= 1 - \mathbb{P}(X_{(1)} > m) - \mathbb{P}(X_{(n)} < m) + 0 \\[6pt]
&= 1 - \frac{1}{2^n} - \frac{1}{2^n} \\[6pt]
&= 1 - \frac{1}{2^{n-1}} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{2^{n-1} - 1}{2^{n-1}}. \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

Note that this result holds for any continuous distribution.  Unsurprisingly, as $n \rightarrow \infty$ we have $\mathbb{P}(X_{(1)} \leqslant m \leqslant X_{(n)}) \rightarrow 1$, so the range of the sample will eventually come to encompass the true median, with probability approaching one.

Comment: Please note that this appears to be a self-study question - indeed the second version was even more clearly so (the one you answerd - though the OP didn't mark it as one, specifically it said something along the lines of "*we have been given no formula to apply*" or something more or less like it);  guidance and hints rather than a complete solution to what appears to be the OP's homework is usually reasonable

Comment: How is this not the same idea of saying that there's a 95% chance of a parameter being in a confidence interval? My first reaction to seeing the question title was that the median isn't a random variable, so we can't make a statement about the probability of the median being in an interval (same as confidence interval vs credible interval)?

Comment: It is very similar.  In this particular case the probability that the interval contains the parameter depends only on $n$, so the "confidence level" can't be varied by the user.  If you wanted to construct a confidence interval where the confidence level can be varied by the user, you would need to construct it using some kind of interval that gets larger or smaller based on some control parameter, and then you would find the relationship of that control parameter to the coverage probability for each fixed $n$.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the general answer but if the continuous distribution is the standard normal then the probability that the median lies between the min and the max of a sample of size $n$ equals

$$ \frac{ 2^{n-1} - 1 }{2^{n-1}} $$

You can work this out based on the distribution of normal order statistics, which I will leave to you as an exercise since this appears to be a self study question.

Comment: I don't think *normality* comes into it. It relates only to order, not to distances, so the calculation would work for any continuous distribution. (Please also see my comment under the other answer.)

Comment: Thanks so much @Glen_b. I only ever thought about it in the context of the normal distribution but I can see you're correct.

Answer (score 0):

pick once from the distribution

then for each subsequent pick, you have a probability 0.5 that your pick is in the same half as the first pick

so your chance of getting all picks on the same side of the median is 0.5^(n-1)

so the chance of that not happening (and therefore the median being contained) is (1-that)

Eg:
n = 5
P = 1 - 0.5^4 = 0.94